# dnsmasq uses many ports

Tags: netstat, dnsmasq

I've executed the command `sudo netstat -veepa -n -W` and found many local ports which are used by `dnsmasq`:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          44220       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7562            0.0.0.0:*                           65534      47002       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48812           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      48565       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20249           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      46993       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41013           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      46995       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           0          44219       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57570           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      49297       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20978           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      48597       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17104           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      48570       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4850            0.0.0.0:*                           65534      46986       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:62450           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      48595       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1067            0.0.0.0:*                           65534      46994       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:13620           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      47618       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9772            0.0.0.0:*                           65534      47027       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54956           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      48516       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38781           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      48555       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30589           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      46987       2983/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30917           0.0.0.0:*                           65534      47558       2983/dnsmasq
```

Is this an expected behavior of `dnsmasq` ?

These many ports appear when:

1. I open the browser.
2. Quickly open many websites on different tabs.
3. The connection is slow, so it takes some time until it connects to the websites.

The number `65534` seems to be related to the user `sync` OR `nobody`, by inspection of `/etc/passwd`:

```
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14 if it matters.

Comment: You ask a lot of questions.  You should restrict each submission to only ask one question so that it can get directed answers.  And your passwd clip does **not** have two users with the same UID, `sync` is UID 4.  They are however in the same *group* which is perfectly normal.

Comment: @MAP Indeed, I deleted the less important questions. Thank you for clarifying! :-)

Comment: all those `LISTEN`s on different ports look unusual to me.  which version of `dnsmasq`?

Comment: You're still saying that sync is same user, but it isn't.  The whole user part is a red herring.  The only user 65534 is nobody, which is completely normal.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with this particular DNS program, but know the DNS in general, so this isn't an answer, but...  If it opens a new UDP port and uses `sendto(` for each outbound query, I can see it having that many queries "on the fly" for some web sites, especially if it's not particularly zealous about closing them.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, DNSMasq will open a new connection for each DNS request to the upstream server and will also receive replies on this same port:

Please see the official [FAQ](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/FAQ) for more information.